# 100% disk full on Centos?

Tags: hard-drive

Can someone tell me, why is this 100% used on the `/`?

How can I fix this problem? I'm not a unix admin, I'm a programmer but can read the books.

```
[root@datasrv /]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              7757352   7757248         0 100% /
/dev/sda1               248895     15027    221018   7% /boot
/dev/sda9            120098680   3173944 110725656   3% /data
tmpfs                   777052         0    777052   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda5              3882508    128136   3553964   4% /home
/dev/sda7              1945132     35888   1808840   2% /tmp
/dev/sda6              7757320   4728956   2627948  65% /usr
/dev/sda3              7757352    571420   6785512   8% /var
```

Follow up:

I deleted some files then ran my rsync program which syncs from a windows mount share drive to a USB drive. It doesn't write to the local Centos disk as far as I know.
Then suddenly the disk drive is full again, why? Does rsync do something that creates lots of files somewhere?

Comment: as root, run `du -sh *`  in / and see where all the space has gone.

Comment: My bet would be on /opt or /root or both ...

Comment: Heh.  We've got a FreeBSD box here that claims that / is 108% full and it still runs fine, maybe it's time to go to BSD.  ;-)  ;-)

Comment: What is the full rsync command you're running?

Comment: Is this a virtual machine or physical?

Answer (score 2):

Find big files and remove them if possible:

> find / -mount -size +8096 -ls
>   find / -mount -name core -ls
>   du -sh /* (and repeat for subsequent dirs on /)

Probably something is flooding your / or you have to many old kernels.
Cleaning up will help, your / should be big enough because you've a seperated /var
and /usr (and /data ...).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check filesize of every directory right in the root, you can use `du -h --max-depth=1 /`. It'll take quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.xsession-error` file. You might refer to this post and see if it helps.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/177058/xsession-errors-file-is-huge-how-can-i-disable

However, since you are running CentOS, I would look in `/etc/x11/xinit` for the `xsession` file. Also, remove the "quotation marks" around the file and get rid of `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see that causes the drive to fill up is the root mail. You might need to empty out your mail for root or whatever other user you need.

**First**

```
du -sh /var/mail/*
```

That should list your mailbox size. If one of them is huge like `root` just run this command to empty it

**Second**

```
> /var/mail/root
```

Make sure you add the greater sign

Your done!

Comment: `/var` is on a separate volume. Truncating root's email will not make any free space on `/`

Comment: It worked for me today